# Scala: Why using self-type instead of mixin produces stackoverflow?

Tags: scala, mixins, traits, self-type

```
trait UserRepository {
  def findByFirstName(firstName: String): Seq[User]
}

trait UserBusinessDelegate extends UserRepository {
  abstract override def findByFirstName(firstName: String) = {
    super.findByFirstName(firstName)
  }
}

class MockUserRepository extends UserRepository {    
  override def findByFirstName(firstName: String) = {
    // whatever
  }
}

val userRepository = new MockUserRepository with UserBusinessDelegate

userRepository.findByFirstName("John") // OK
```

However, if I change `UserBusinessDelegate` as follows:

```
trait UserBusinessDelegate {
  self: UserRepository =>
  override def findByFirstName(firstName: String): Seq[User] = {
    self.findByFirstName(firstName) // requires explicit return type, thinks this is a recursive call
  }
}

val userRepository = new MockUserRepository with UserBusinessDelegate

userRepository.findByFirstName("John") // StackOverflow!!!
```

I understand stackable pattern and hence how the first case works. My question is why the 2nd doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second snippet you have a recursive call without an exit condition:

```
override def findByFirstName(firstName: String): Seq[User] = {
    self.findByFirstName(firstName)
}
```

This will always call `findByFirstName` from `UserBusinessDelegate` (because you're using `self`, which basically says that this object will have this kind of behaviour at runtime, not that it's parent will have it and therefore we should call parent's method) creating a new stack frame with each call -> stack overflow.

In the second snippet `UserBusinessDelegate`'s `findByFirstName` will be called and then you call `MockUserRepository`'s method from it using `super` -> no recursion -> no stack overflow. You can check [Scala's stackable trait pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html) for more info.

@Edit: to make it more clear, in the snippet that throws a SO exception the `findByFirstName` method from `MockUserRepository` won't be called because you are overriding it in `UserBusinessDelegate` therefore the anonymous class created with `new MockUserRepository with UserBusinessDelegate` will only contain the overriden method and that's why the SO, is that clear?

Why would you assume that the method from `MockUserRepository` would get invoked?

@Edit2: the code doesn't compile without `override` because `self: UserRepository =>` tells the compiler that a method with such a signature will already be there at runtime and you cannot have 2 methods with the same signature. The first example works only because it's a stackable trait, such traits are dynamically bound and can modify the behaviour but have to call `super` at some point (which normally isn't allowed without the `abstract override` modifier, I really recommend going through the link I posted about stackable pattern).

Maybe someone else knows a way, from what I know there's no way to call the mock method unless you change the method name in `UserBusinessDelegate` and drop the `override`, then you can call `self.findByFirstName` and it will call the method from `MockUserRepository`.

Comment: I don't think how you explained the stack overflow is entirely correct. `UserBusinessDelegate` doesn't call itself infinitely.

I understand stackable pattern and hence how first case works. My question is why the 2nd doesn't. What I expected to happen in the 2nd case was `UserBusinessDelegate` called `MockUserRepository`. What actually happens is that the calls back and forth between the anonymous class `new MockUserRepository with UserBusinessDelegate` and  `UserBusinessDelegate`. `MockUserRepository` is never called.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar please see my edit, you are overriding `MockUserRepository`'s method so it will never get called

Comment: So in case of mixin, the left one is called first ( `MockUserRepository`) but in case of self-type, the last ones wins (`UserBusinessDelegate`), even though `MockUserRepository` has an implementation for `findByFirstName`? The code doesn't compile if I don't override in `UserBusinessDelegate`. Is it possible to somehow call the method from `MockUserRepository` using self type?